# Basic PHP loop RBL checker array

Tags: php, arrays, string, url, loops

I am trying to create a basic RBL checker in PHP, I can't seem to get the IP to be added on the end of the url with out error. I am not the best with PHP.

`list.inc` is just a list of IPs to check each IP is on a new line.

```
<?
$ips = file("list.inc");
foreach($ips as $ip)
{
$rblurl = 'http://rbl-check.org/rbl_api.php?ipaddress=' . $ip;
//$rblcheckurl = $rblurl . $ip;
$boom = fopen($rblurl, "r");
//print "<pre>";
//print_r($boom);
//print "</pre>";
$rbl = stream_get_contents($boom);
echo "</br>";
$data = explode(";",$rbl);
print_r($data);
echo "</br>";
fclose($boom);
}
?>
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: well, what do you get, then? `var_dump($rblurl)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values returned by `file()` include the newline at the end of each line, you need to remove them before appending them to the URL:

```
foreach ($ips as $ip) {
  $rblurl = 'http://rbl-check.org/rbl_api.php?ipaddress=' . trim($ip);
  ...
}
```